# Organizar/Unir Datos Rstudio en un data frame

Tags: base-de-datos, r, rstudio, dataframe

Tengo un Dataframe con la siguiente información:

```
Ciudad de destino    Tipo de Equipo    Num Vuelos   
Madrid                    A319              4
Barcelona                 B767              2
Alicante                  A320              3
Madrid                    A319              5
Sevilla                   A231              4
Cadiz                     B760              3 
Cadis                     B732              8 
Madrid                    A319              2
Barcelona                 B324              8   
Sevilla                   A321              7
```

Estoy intentando organizar un `dataframe` nuevo que me diga que tipo de equipo viajo a que ciudad y cuantas veces, ya que hay varios tipos de avión que van al mismo destino.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas es hacer una agregación, con R base puedes hacer algo así:

```
aggregate(`Num Vuelos` ~ `Tipo de Equipo`, df, sum)
```

Comentarios:

- Nota que estoy usando backticks para encerrar los nombres de las columnas, te recomiendo que no uses espacios en estos, por que te obliga a hacer esto
- En primer lugar establecemos la formula que agrupa por tipo de equipo y agrega sombre el número de vuelos.
- La función de agregación en este caso es `sum()`

Comment: Hola, lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente forma y tengo un error                                                            `> aggregate(Ciudad_Destino ~Tipo_Equipo+Num_Vuelos,DataBaase_NAL2018_MASEMISS, sum) 
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 'type' (character) de argumento no válido`                                  Lo hago de esta forma ya que quiero saber cuantas veces van los diferentes tipos de avión a un mismo destino. Sabes a que se debe el error y si lo estoy haciendo bien?

Comment: - En la columna Ciudad_Destino se repiten varias veces las ciudades destino ya que son son los datos de varias aerolíneas viajando a los mismos destino.            -Elimine los espacios en los títulos de las columnas como lo sugeriste

Comment: @Santiago, has agregado columnas a la formula que seguramente son del tipo `character`, de ahí el error ya que no se puede aplicar el `sum` a estas.

Comment: Tal vez estas buscando sea algo como esto: `aggregate(Num_Vuelos~Tipo_Equipo+Ciudad_Destino ,DataBaase_NAL2018_MASEMISS, sum)`

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio.

Answer (score 0):

Hola te muestro otra manera en lo que los puedes resolver utilizando un librería llamada dplyr, el resultado final el lo que se muestra hasta abajo, por cierto el error que mencionas parece que es porque esta intentando sumar un tipo "character" , es importante ver que tipo de columna es el que quieres sumar puedes para esto usar "class()"

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

#Replico la base de datos que estas mostrando 
df<-data.frame(Ciudad_de_destino=c("Madrid","Barcelona","Alicante","Madrid", 
                "Sevilla","Cadiz","Cadis","Madrid","Barcelona","Sevilla"),
               Tipo_de_Equipo=c("A319","B767","A320" 
               "A319","A231","B760","B732","A319","B324","A321"),
               Num_Vuelos=c(4,2,3,5,4,3,8,2,8,7))

#Agrupo las variables por ciudad y equino y luego sumo el numero de vuelo
 df %>% group_by(Ciudad_de_destino,Tipo_de_Equipo) %>%
                summarise(Veces=sum(Num_Vuelos))
 # A tibble: 8 x 3
 # Groups:   Ciudad_de_destino [6]
 Ciudad_de_destino Tipo_de_Equipo Veces
 <fct>             <fct>          <dbl>
1 Alicante          A320               3
2 Barcelona         B324               8
3 Barcelona         B767               2
4 Cadis             B732               8
5 Cadiz             B760               3
6 Madrid            A319              11
7 Sevilla           A231               4
8 Sevilla           A321               7
```

Comment: Hola Ruben, efectivamente usando tu explicación pude obtener lo que estaba buscando. muchas gracias!